# updating and merging elements in an array of structs

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I would like to update entries in a given array so that if `ptr_shost/ptr_dhost` pairs are the same i would simply store the updated fields in the same `ptr_shost/ptr_dhost` pairs.May you point to me when I am making the errors,because I see some values are just repeated which is not what i would like.Below is my code:

```
void mysort(struct my_mac data[],int n){
    int j,i = 0,k;
    struct my_mac temp[1000];
    while(i < n){
        for(j = i+1; j < n; j++){
            char src1[20];
            char dst1[20];
            char src2[20];
            char dst2[20];
            ether_ntoa_r(data[i].ptr_shost,src1);
            ether_ntoa_r(data[i].ptr_dhost,dst1);
            ether_ntoa_r(data[j].ptr_shost,src2);
            ether_ntoa_r(data[j].ptr_dhost,dst2);
            int comp1 = strcmp(src1, src2);
            int comp2 = strcmp(dst1,dst2);
            if( comp1 == 0 && comp2 == 0 && i!=j){
                temp[i].ptr_shost  = data[j].ptr_shost;
                temp[i].ptr_dhost  = data[j].ptr_dhost;
                temp[i].packets = data[j].packets;
                temp[i].octets += data[j].octets;
            }else{
                temp[i].ptr_shost  = data[j].ptr_shost;
                temp[i].ptr_dhost  = data[i].ptr_dhost;
                temp[i].packets  = data[j].packets;
                temp[i].octets = data[j].octets;
            }

        }i++;
    }
```

EDIT:added the struct

```
 struct my_mac {
    u_char *ptr_dhost;
    u_char *ptr_shost;
    int octets;
    int packets;
  };
```

Comment: Why not just using `qsort`? It is ready from the C header. You can pass a compare function, so that structs can be compared. I have an example here: http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/qsort-c/

Comment: I assume this is homework and you can't use pre-existing sorting routines?

Comment: it's part of a homework of course,but this particular piece has no limit as to how it is implemented,so i accept any other pre-existing method(which may,on a side note keep the code short)

Comment: you can likely make this *significantly* simpler if you could update your question text to include how the struct `my_mac` is actually defined, and in particular how the `ptr_shost` and `ptr_dhost` members are defined. A custom comparator tailored to compare two of these structs in combination with `qsort()` will likely be near-trivial, and if possible to compare the data those pointers reference without conversion, even faster.

Comment: It's impossible to know what's really going on in your code from the fragment you provide, but your code doesn't show any guarantees of avoiding duplication. And where does the sorting comparison happen?

Comment: essentially,this is not sorting but grouping pairs which are the same.What I am doing is sniff on ethernet packets and then list the source/destination MAC addresses without rewriting the pairs that are the same,but just update some other info like the number of cumulative octets and all